# How to add ctrl-key to an occuring click event?

Tags: jquery

I'm adding a multi-select element to my website. The behaviour I want to get is, normal click-events on elements of the multi-select-list should be handled als ctrl+click.

I'm on a beginner level in jQuery and do not really have an idea how to approach this problem.

I tried to "catch" the events with

```
$('.ui-selectlistbox-item').on("click", function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   console.log("item was clicked");
});
```

I think this should prevent the normal click.

How would I add the new ctrl+click event on the same target?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
if (event.ctrlKey)
```

Use `console.log(event)` to see the event object

Comment: If I understand correctly, this would help me to only get the events that have the ctrl-key already pressed.
I want to alter the incoming click events so every click has ctrlKey pressed, no matter if the user pressed the key or not.

Comment: no. it is all click events. you put if statement inside of the click event handler and check, was the enter key pressed or no